# Xsl transformation removing parts of xml

Tags: xml, xslt

Hello I've been trying to remove some parts of xml for a while now and it's simply not working for me. Let me begin by listing my requirements :

**1.** Remove all node attributes which value is blank or values' length < 1 like in example :

`<pr:Text default="" approved="true" type="">Mon-Sun 12HR</pr:Text>`

should become `<pr:Text approved="true">Mon-Sun 12HR</pr:Text>`

I think I got this part covered with this (I think), please correct me if I'm wrong :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:if test=". != ''">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**2.** Remove entire node(element) whose children don't have text value, example :

```
<pr:WorkingHoursInfo>
    <pr:WorkingHoursList>
              <pr:WorkingHours dayOfweek="MONDAY">
            </pr:WorkingHours>
              <pr:WorkingHours dayOfweek="TUESDAY">
            </pr:WorkingHours>
              <pr:WorkingHours dayOfweek="WEDNESDAY">
            </pr:WorkingHours>
              <pr:WorkingHours dayOfweek="THURSDAY">
            </pr:WorkingHours>
              <pr:WorkingHours dayOfweek="FRIDAY">
            </pr:WorkingHours>
              <pr:WorkingHours dayOfweek="SATURDAY">
            </pr:WorkingHours>
              <pr:WorkingHours dayOfweek="SUNDAY">
            </pr:WorkingHours>
    </pr:WorkingHoursList>
</pr:WorkingHoursInfo>
```

Should become :

```
<pr:WorkingHoursInfo>
</pr:WorkingHoursInfo>
```

So I should do these 2 transformations in one go if possible. I'm currently stuck on this #2 any help is appriciated

**Question update :**

Per `Martin Honnen` answer changed xsl file to :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*[not(normalize-space())]"/>
<xsl:template match="*[not(*/*) and not(*[normalize-space()])]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But now the requirement **1.** is violated now `<pr:Text default="" approved="true" type="">Mon-Sun 12HR</pr:Text>` gets deleted from xml.

**Another update :**

from `Martin Honnen` almost working, so `1` is working and `2` is working(almost). One exception being that single elements without children which have no text value are not being removed i.e :

`<pr:DescriptionAttribute Type="PRIMARY"/>`

This should be deleted as well. So it's almost working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

then add templates for the tasks you have i.e.

```
<xsl:template match="@*[not(normalize-space())]"/>
```

ensures the empty attributes are deleted and

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space()) and not(*/*) and not(*[normalize-space()])]"/>
```

ensures that elements not having any grand child elements and not having a child containing text are deleted.

[edit]
Here is a complete stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="@*[not(normalize-space())]"/>

<xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space()) and not(*/*) and not(*[normalize-space()])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I use Saxon 6.5.5 to apply that stylesheet on the input

```
<pr:root
  xmlns:pr="http://example.com/pr">

<pr:WorkingHoursInfo>
    <pr:WorkingHoursList>
              <pr:WorkingHours dayOfweek="MONDAY">
            </pr:WorkingHours>
              <pr:WorkingHours dayOfweek="TUESDAY">
            </pr:WorkingHours>
              <pr:WorkingHours dayOfweek="WEDNESDAY">
            </pr:WorkingHours>
              <pr:WorkingHours dayOfweek="THURSDAY">
            </pr:WorkingHours>
              <pr:WorkingHours dayOfweek="FRIDAY">
            </pr:WorkingHours>
              <pr:WorkingHours dayOfweek="SATURDAY">
            </pr:WorkingHours>
              <pr:WorkingHours dayOfweek="SUNDAY">
            </pr:WorkingHours>
    </pr:WorkingHoursList>
</pr:WorkingHoursInfo>

<pr:Text default="" approved="true" type="">Mon-Sun 12HR</pr:Text>

<pr:DescriptionAttribute Type="PRIMARY"/>

</pr:root>
```

then the result is

```
<pr:root xmlns:pr="http://example.com/pr">

<pr:WorkingHoursInfo>

</pr:WorkingHoursInfo>

<pr:Text approved="true">Mon-Sun 12HR</pr:Text>



</pr:root>
```

so the empty element `<pr:DescriptionAttribute Type="PRIMARY"/>` is removed.

Comment: I have edited one template, hopefully that takes care of preventing elements from being deleted that have text content.

Comment: Ok Sir you're so close, please see my update (+1 forgot in first place)

Comment: Thanks your solution is complete in regards to the question I asked, one more thing what would I need to change in the template if I were to remove `<pr:WorkingHoursInfo>` element as well. Thank you